# Paper.js Background Rasterization Glitches

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, raster, paperjs

We are building an image editor of sorts using Paper.js. We have a queue on the side of the Paper.js canvas that allows switching between images. Each time we switch between images, we want to flatten all the annotations (rasterize) onto the image just being edited.

Each time we switch images, this method is called, which rasterizes the current image and annotations to a data URL. (If we revisit this image, a raster from this data URL will be displayed.)

```
var flattenToDataUrl = function() {
  layerAsRaster = paper.project.layers[0].rasterize(); // Layer to Paper.js Raster object
  layerAsRaster.visible = false; // Attempt to set not visible
  var dataString = layerAsRaster.toDataURL();
  return dataString;
};
```

Then we end up calling this method, which changes out the image we're editing:

```
var setCanvasImage = function(imageObject) {
  if(imageObject != null)
  {
    imageHeight = imageObject.height;
    var imageWidth = imageObject.width;

    // Set up HTMLImage
    var imageElement = new Image(imageObject.width, imageObject.height);
    if(_.has(imageObject, 'imageData')) { // Came as 64 bit data
      imageElement.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + imageObject.imageData;
    } else if(_.has(imageObject, 'imageUrl')) { // Came as URL
      imageElement.src = imageObject.imageUrl;
    }

    // Add image to Paper.js canvas
    imageElement.onload = function(event) {

      // Initialize Paper.js on the canvas
      paper.setup(canvas);

      raster = new paper.Raster(imageElement, new paper.Point(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2));

      setUpNotes();

      selectedItems = new paper.Group(); // Since Paper.js has been setup we can now initialize this Group
      registerCanvasEvents(); // Panning, zooming, moving selected items, deselecting all selected items

      fitToPage();
    };
  }
};
```

So, this changes out the image, but when I move my mouse into the canvas after selecting a different image in the queue, it glitches to the image we were just on (with its annotations) until I do something like pan, zoom, etc. Then I see the image I selected and am truly working with.

Removing the `flattenToDataUrl()` functionality makes the queue work seamlessly. So it seems to me something is fishy there. We are generating a Paper.js Raster object in that method. Rasters seem to automatically add themselves. I attempt to curb this with a call to

```
layerAsRaster.visible = false;
```

but to no avail.

What is causing this glitchy behavior and how do I prevent it?

**Update**

For clarity (hopefully) and completeness, I've decided to post the whole PaperFunctions class we use in conjunction with React, which hosts our `<canvas>` element. There's a lot of code, and a lot of cleanup to do, especially in `registerCanvasEvents()`. Bear with this learning beginner. Also it's several hundred lines, so it may be helpful to paste it into your favorite editor. Entry points include `setCanvas` which is called in `componentDidMount` of the React class with the `<canvas>` element, and `canvasSetImage` which is called from the queue. I agree from bmacnaughton's answer that it's weird to call `paper.setup(canvas)` every time we load a new image. I'm currently investigating the right solution to this, the right place to put it. `setCanvas` seems logical but when I drag the image to move it in that setup, it leaves a trail of images in its wake. Anyway, here's PaperFunctions.js:

```
var JQueryMousewheel = require('jquery-mousewheel')($);

var SimplePanAndZoom = require('./SimplePanAndZoom.js');
var panAndZoom = new SimplePanAndZoom();

var selectedItems;

// We use selection here in two distinct ways.
// An item may be Paper.js selected but not in the selection group.
// This is because we want to show it is selectable.
// A blue bounding box indicates it is selectable.
// A green bounding box indicates it has actually been selected and added to selectedItems.
// Only things in selectedItems are actually operated on.
// So the event handlers in this method basically set up whether or not the item is in selectedItems (and therefore will be operated on for moving, resizing, deleting, etc.).
// That is, the event handlers here are concerned with displaying to the user the status of selection for the item - whether or not it will be operated on when events actually happen on the selectedItems Group.
var registerItemEvents = function(item) {
  // Boolean flag for mouseup to know if was drag or click
  var dragged;

  // For tracking if dragging or clicking is happening
  item.on('mousedown', function(e) {
    dragged = false;
  });

  // On click toggle selection
  item.on('mouseup', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation(); // Only for item applied to
    event.preventDefault();

    if(!dragged) {
      var justAdded = addIfNotInSelectedItems(item);
      if(!justAdded) { // Item was in selection group, remove it
        item.remove();
        paper.project.activeLayer.addChild(item);

        this.selectedColor = paper.project.activeLayer.selectedColor;
        //item.selected = false;
      }
    }
  });

  // Show as selectable even after has been deselected
  item.on('mousemove', function(event) {
    this.selected = true;
  })

  // If not selected, on mouse enter show that it is selectable
  item.on('mouseenter', function(event) {
    if(!this.selected) {
      this.selected = true;
    }
  });

  // If not selected, on mouse leave remove indicator that is selectable
  item.on('mouseleave', function(event) {
    var isInSelectedItems = selectedItems.getItem(item);
    if(this.selected && isInSelectedItems == null) {
      this.selected = false;
    }
  });

  // On drag, move item
  item.on('mousedrag', function(event) {
    dragged = true;

    // If user starts dragging automatically select the item
    addIfNotInSelectedItems(item);
  });
}

var addIfNotInSelectedItems = function(item) {
  var isInSelectedItems = selectedItems.getItem(item);
  if(isInSelectedItems == null) { // Item not currently in selection group, add it
    selectedItems.addChild(item);
    item.selectedColor = 'green';
    item.selected = true;
    return true; // Was added, return true
  } else {
    return false; // Already in, return false
  }
}

var registerCanvasEvents = function() {
  if(paper.view != null && canvas != null) {
    // Zoom on mousewheel
    $(canvas).mousewheel(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var mousePosition = new paper.Point(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
      var viewPosition = paper.view.viewToProject(mousePosition);
      var returnedValues = panAndZoom.changeZoom(paper.view.zoom, (event.deltaY * -1), paper.view.center, viewPosition, 1.1);
      var newZoom = returnedValues[0];
      var offset = returnedValues[1];
      paper.view.zoom = newZoom;
      paper.view.center = paper.view.center.add(offset);
    });

    // For tracking if dragging or clicking is happening
    var dragged;
    paper.project.layers[0].on('mousedown', function(e) { // TODO should be layer 0 in long run?
      dragged = false;
    });


    // Pan on mouse drag
    /*paper.project.layers[0].on('mousedrag', function(event) { // TODO should be layer 0 in long run?
      if(!event.event.ctrlKey && !event.event.altKey && !event.event.shiftKey) { // No keys (that we use) can be pushed
        dragged = true; // We're panning, we don't wish to deselect all items as we would do with a click
        paper.view.center = panAndZoom.changeCenter(paper.view.center, event.delta.x, event.delta.y, 0.7);
        //event.preventDefault();
      }
    });*/

    // Move selected items on mouse drag
    selectedItems.on('mousedrag', function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation(); // Don't propogate up or it will register as a pan event
      event.preventDefault();

      dragged = true; // We're panning, we don't wish to deselect all items as we would do with a click

      this.translate(new paper.Point(event.delta.x, event.delta.y));
    });

    // If was a click and not a drag, deselect selected items
    paper.project.layers[0].on('mouseup', function(event) {
      if(!dragged) {
        var removedItems = selectedItems.removeChildren(); // Remove from selection group, which also removes from display
        paper.project.activeLayer.addChildren(removedItems); // Return to display

        // Reset selection colors for showing selectable
        for(var i =0; i < removedItems.length; i++) {
          removedItems[i].selectedColor = paper.project.activeLayer.selectedColor;
          removedItems[i].selected = false;
        }
      }
    });

    // Initial path object, will be reset for new paths after Alt is released
    var path = newPath();
    var paths = [];
    paths.push(path);

    // On mousedown add point to start from
    paper.project.layers[0].on('mousedown', function(event) {
      if(event.event.altKey && !event.event.ctrlKey) { // Alt key to add a path, but disallow attempting to add text at the same time
        if(paths[paths.length-1].lastSegment == null) {
          //path.add(event.point, event.point);
          paths[paths.length-1].add(event.point, event.point);
        } else {
          //path.add(path.lastSegment.point, path.lastSegment.point);
          paths[paths.length-1].add(paths[paths.length-1].lastSegment.point, paths[paths.length-1].lastSegment.point);
        }
      }
    });

    // On mousedrag add points to path
    paper.project.layers[0].on('mousedrag', function(event) {
      if(event.event.altKey && !event.event.ctrlKey) { // Alt key to add a path, but disallow attempting to add text at the same time
        if(event.event.shiftKey) { // Use shift key for freeform
          //path.add(event.point);
          paths[paths.length-1].add(event.point);
        } else { // Default of straight line added to path
          //path.lastSegment.point = event.point;
          paths[paths.length-1].lastSegment.point = event.point;
        }
      }
    }.bind(this));

    var tool = new paper.Tool();

    var startDragPoint;

    // Capture start of drag selection
    paper.tool.onMouseDown = function(event) {
      if((event.event.ctrlKey && event.event.shiftKey) || (event.event.ctrlKey && event.event.altKey)) {
        startDragPoint = new paper.Point(event.point);
      }
    };

    paper.tool.onMouseDrag = function(event) {
      // Panning
      if(!event.event.ctrlKey && !event.event.altKey && !event.event.shiftKey) { // No keys (that we use) can be pushed
        dragged = true; // We're panning, we don't wish to deselect all items as we would do with a click
        paper.view.center = panAndZoom.changeCenter(paper.view.center, event.delta.x, event.delta.y, 0.7);
        //event.preventDefault();
      }

      // Show box indicating the area that has been selected
      // For moving area and whiting out area
      if((event.event.ctrlKey && event.event.shiftKey) || (event.event.ctrlKey && event.event.altKey)) {
        dragged = true;
        var showSelection = new paper.Path.Rectangle({
            from: startDragPoint,
            to: event.point,
            strokeColor: 'red',
            strokeWidth: 1
        });

        // Stop showing the selected area on drag (new one is created) and up because we're done
        showSelection.removeOn({
            drag: true,
            up: true
        });
      }
    };

    // Capture start of drag selection
    paper.tool.onMouseUp = function(event) {
      if((event.event.ctrlKey && event.event.shiftKey) || (event.event.ctrlKey && event.event.altKey)) {
        var endDragPoint = new paper.Point(event.point);
        if(event.event.ctrlKey && event.event.shiftKey) { // Whiteout area
          whiteoutArea(startDragPoint, endDragPoint);
        } else if(event.event.ctrlKey && event.event.altKey) { // Move selected area
          selectArea(startDragPoint, endDragPoint);
        }
      }
    };

    // Key events
    paper.tool.onKeyUp = function(event) {
      // Delete selected items on delete key
      if(event.key == 'delete') {
        selectedItems.removeChildren();
      } else if (event.key == 'option') {
        registerItemEvents(paths[paths.length-1]);

        // Start a new path
        paths.push(newPath());
      }
    }
  }
}

// These variables are scoped so that all methods in PaperFunctions can access them
var canvas; // Set by setCanvas
var imageHeight; // Set by setCanvasImage

var raster;

var toolsSetup = false;

var setCanvas = function(canvasElement) {
  canvas = canvasElement;
  paper.setup(canvas);
};

var setCanvasImage = function(imageObject) {
  if(imageObject != null)
  {
    imageHeight = imageObject.height;
    var imageWidth = imageObject.width;

    // Set up HTMLImage
    var imageElement = new Image(imageObject.width, imageObject.height);
    if(_.has(imageObject, 'imageData')) { // Came as 64 bit data
      imageElement.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + imageObject.imageData;
    } else if(_.has(imageObject, 'imageUrl')) { // Came as URL
      imageElement.src = imageObject.imageUrl;
    }

    // Add image to Paper.js canvas
    imageElement.onload = function(event) {
      //canvas.height = $(document).height()-3; // Set canvas height. Why do this here and not in the React component? Because we set the width here too, so we're keeping those together. Perhaps in the future this will be changed when we are responsive to window resizing.
      //scalingFactor = canvas.height / imageObject.height; // Determine the ratio
      //canvas.width = imageElement.width * scalingFactor; // Scale width based on height; canvas height has been set to the height of the document

      // Initialize Paper.js on the canvas
      paper.setup(canvas);

      raster = new paper.Raster(imageElement, new paper.Point(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2));

      //setUpLineAndFreeFormDrawing(); // TODO once we cycle through images will we need to reset this for each new image or can we do this just once?

      setUpNotes(); // TODO once we cycle through images will we need to reset this for each new image or can we do this just once?

      selectedItems = new paper.Group(); // Since Paper.js has been setup we can now initialize this Group
      registerCanvasEvents(); // Panning, zooming, moving selected items, deselecting all selected items

      fitToPage();
    };
  }
};

var fitToPage = function() {
  if(paper.view != null && canvas != null) {
    // Fit image to page so whole thing is displayed
    var scalingFactor = canvas.height / imageHeight; // Constant representation of the ratio of the canvas size to the image size
    var zoomFactor = scalingFactor / paper.view.zoom; // Dynamic representation of the zoom needed to return to viewing the whole image in the canvas

    // Reset the center point to the center of the canvas
    var canvasCenter = new paper.Point(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
    paper.view.center = canvasCenter;

    // Zoom to fit the whole image in the canvas
    var returnedValues = panAndZoom.changeZoom(paper.view.zoom, -1, canvasCenter, canvasCenter, zoomFactor); // Always pass -1 as the delta, not entirely sure why
    var newZoom = returnedValues[0];
    var offset = returnedValues[1];
    paper.view.zoom = newZoom;
    paper.view.center = paper.view.center.add(offset);
  }
};

var addImage = function(imageDataUrl) {
  if(paper.view != null) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = imageDataUrl;
    var presentMomentForId = new Date().getTime() + "-image"; // For purposes of having unique IDs
    img.id = presentMomentForId;
    img.hidden = true;
    document.body.appendChild(img);

    var raster = new paper.Raster(presentMomentForId);

    registerItemEvents(raster);
  }
};

var setUpLineAndFreeFormDrawing = function() {
  if(paper.project != null) {
    // Initial path object, will be reset for new paths after Alt is released
    var path = newPath();
    var paths = [];
    paths.push(path);

    // On mousedown add point to start from
    paper.project.layers[0].on('mousedown', function(event) {
      if(event.event.altKey && !event.event.ctrlKey) { // Alt key to add a path, but disallow attempting to add text at the same time
        if(paths[paths.length-1].lastSegment == null) {
          //path.add(event.point, event.point);
          paths[paths.length-1].add(event.point, event.point);
        } else {
          //path.add(path.lastSegment.point, path.lastSegment.point);
          paths[paths.length-1].add(paths[paths.length-1].lastSegment.point, paths[paths.length-1].lastSegment.point);
        }
      }
    });

    // On mousedrag add points to path
    paper.project.layers[0].on('mousedrag', function(event) {
      if(event.event.altKey && !event.event.ctrlKey) { // Alt key to add a path, but disallow attempting to add text at the same time
        if(event.event.shiftKey) { // Use shift key for freeform
          //path.add(event.point);
          paths[paths.length-1].add(event.point);
        } else { // Default of straight line added to path
          //path.lastSegment.point = event.point;
          paths[paths.length-1].lastSegment.point = event.point;
        }
      }
    }.bind(this));

    // Each time Alt comes up, start a new path
    paper.tool.onKeyUp = function(event) {
      if(event.key == "option") {
        registerItemEvents(paths[paths.length-1]);

        // Start a new path
        paths.push(newPath());
      }
    };
  }
};

// Establishes default line style
var newPath = function() {
  var path = new paper.Path();
  path.strokeColor = 'black';
  path.strokeWidth = 10;
  return path;
};

var note = "";
var setNote = function(newNote) {
  note = newNote;
};

var setUpNotes = function() {
  if(paper.project != null) {
    paper.project.layers[0].on('mousedown', function(event) { // TODO should be layer 0 in long run?
      if(event.event.ctrlKey && !event.event.altKey && !event.event.shiftKey) { // Only Ctrl key to add text

        // Add text box
        var textBox = new paper.PointText(event.point);
        textBox.justification = 'left';
        textBox.fillColor = 'black';
        textBox.fontSize = 60;
        textBox.content = note;

        registerItemEvents(textBox);
      }
    });
  }
};

var selectArea = function(startDragPoint, endDragPoint) {
  var rasterTopLeftCorner = new paper.Point(raster.bounds.topLeft);
  var adjustedStartDragPoint = new paper.Point(startDragPoint.x - rasterTopLeftCorner.x, startDragPoint.y - rasterTopLeftCorner.y);
  var adjustedEndDragPoint = new paper.Point(endDragPoint.x - rasterTopLeftCorner.x, endDragPoint.y - rasterTopLeftCorner.y);
  var boundingRectangleRasterCoordinates = new paper.Rectangle(adjustedStartDragPoint, adjustedEndDragPoint);
  var boundingRectangleCanvasCoordinates = new paper.Rectangle(startDragPoint, endDragPoint);

  var selectedArea = raster.getSubRaster(boundingRectangleRasterCoordinates);

  var whitedOutSelection = new paper.Shape.Rectangle(boundingRectangleCanvasCoordinates);
  whitedOutSelection.fillColor = 'white';
  whitedOutSelection.insertAbove(raster); // Whiteout just above the image we're working with

  registerItemEvents(selectedArea);
}

var whiteoutArea = function(startDragPoint, endDragPoint) {
  var whitedOutSelection = new paper.Shape.Rectangle(startDragPoint, endDragPoint);
  whitedOutSelection.fillColor = 'white';
  whitedOutSelection.insertAbove(raster); // Whiteout just above the image we're working with
}

var flattenToDataUrl = function() {
  layerAsRaster = paper.project.layers[0].rasterize(); // TODO should be layer 0 in long run? // Layer to Paper.js Raster object
  layerAsRaster.visible = false;
  var dataString = layerAsRaster.toDataURL();
  return dataString;
};

module.exports = {
  setCanvas: setCanvas,
  setCanvasImage: setCanvasImage,
  fitToPage: fitToPage,
  addImage: addImage,
  setNote: setNote,
  flattenToDataUrl: flattenToDataUrl
};
```

Additionally, here's the SimplePanAndZoom.js file for clarity. It uses minimal Paper functions, it mainly just does calculations:

```
// Based on http://matthiasberth.com/articles/stable-zoom-and-pan-in-paperjs/

var SimplePanAndZoom = (function() {
  function SimplePanAndZoom() { }

  SimplePanAndZoom.prototype.changeZoom = function(oldZoom, delta, centerPoint, offsetPoint, zoomFactor) {
    var newZoom = oldZoom;
    if (delta < 0) {
      newZoom = oldZoom * zoomFactor;
    }
    if (delta > 0) {
      newZoom = oldZoom / zoomFactor;
    }

    // Zoom towards offsetPoint, not centerPoint (unless they're the same)
    var a = null;
    if(!centerPoint.equals(offsetPoint)) {
      var scalingFactor = oldZoom / newZoom;
      var difference = offsetPoint.subtract(centerPoint);
      a = offsetPoint.subtract(difference.multiply(scalingFactor)).subtract(centerPoint);
    }

    return [newZoom, a];
  };

  SimplePanAndZoom.prototype.changeCenter = function(oldCenter, deltaX, deltaY, factor) {
    var offset;
    offset = new paper.Point(-deltaX, -deltaY);
    offset = offset.multiply(factor);
    return oldCenter.add(offset);
  };

  return SimplePanAndZoom;

})();

module.exports = SimplePanAndZoom;
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think it would be a lot easier if you used layers and toggled the visibility & activity when selecting another base image. That way you don't have to  (un)load your annotations when switching between rasters. Is there a reason that you're using distinct projects instead?

Comment: @AlexBlackwood That seems reasonable. Until it was pointed out I wasn't aware I was using separate projects.

Comment: That's definitely the approach I'd take. As @bmacnaughton mentioned, it's better to use paper.project.activeLayer for the current layer. You can set which is active from your queue with paper.project.layers[index].activate().

Comment: @AlexBlackwood - I agree that multiple layers seems like the right way to do this.  It was odd though that paper cleared the first project when the second project was created. Even using the same canvas I didn't expect that behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm taking some guesses here but I'll address some problems in the code that will hopefully address the behavior you're seeing.

First, I presume `paper.project.layers[0]` is `paper.project.activeLayer`. Once that has been rasterized 1) the raster is added to the layer and setting `visible = false` does cause it to disappear when an update is done.

Second, when you invoke `paper.setup(canvas)` in `imageElement.onload` you create a new paper project. This project starts out as the active project and makes the previous project "disappear". So when you create a raster with `raster = new paper.Raster(...)` it goes into the new project, not the old project.

So now there is a hidden (`.visible = false`) raster in the old project (let's call it project1) and a new version of it in project2.

I'm not sure if this is the intended behavior or not, but when you invoke `paper.setup(canvas)` for what seems to be the second time then paper seems to notice that they both refer to the same canvas and keeps project1 and project2 in sync. So creating the second project clears the first project's children array. And adding `new paper.Raster(...)` ends up adding the raster to project1 and project2.

Now I can't tell what the next piece of the puzzle is. You'd need to add some information like 1) where the mouse event handlers are setup and what they are attached to, 2) what setUpNotes() does, 3) what registerCanvasEvents() does, and 4) what fitToPage does.

There are a few globals created, `imageHeight` and `raster` that probably aren't intentional. And it's not clear why you need to use `new Image()` at all - `paper.Raster()` accepts URLs, including data URLs.

I was surprised paper cleared the first project. It's curious.

Version 2:

Let me take a stab at structuring this using layers. I'd suggest you get rid of multiple projects because having mouse event handlers attached to multiple projects that share the same canvas adds too much complexity.

So, in your code initialization: `paper.setup(canvas)`. Do this once and only once.

Setup the initial image in the single layer initially created by paper.

```
// this will be inserted into the current layer, project.activeLayer
var raster = new paper.Raster(imageURL, paper.view.bounds.center);
```

When the image in your queue changes do something like:

```
// make the existing image/layer invisible
paper.project.activeLayer.visible = false;

// add a new layer which is inserted in the project and activated
var layer = new paper.Layer();

// the new layer is activated, create a raster for the image
var raster = new paper.Raster(imageURL, paper.view.bounds.center);

// now do your normal logic for editing, zooming, etc.
```

It's really a bit more complicated than that because you have a queue of images and you only want to create a layer the first time you visit an image. You could initialize all the rasters at the outset, something like:

```
var imageURLs = ["url to image1", "url to image2", "etc"];
imageURLs.forEach(function(url) {
    new paper.Layer();
    paper.project.activeLayer.visible = false;
    new paper.Raster(url, paper.view.bounds.center);
});
// make the first layer visible and activate it
paper.project.layers[0].visible = true;
paper.project.layers[0].activate();
```

The preceeding code gives you a parallel array to the images in your queue so switching images is straightforward - there is no checking to see if that image has been created or not:

```
function setImage(index) {
    paper.project.activeLayer.visible = false;
    paper.project.layers[index].activate();
    paper.project.layers[index].visible = true;
}
```

Finally, I would make sure my mouse handling wasn't causing me problems. From the new code you posted it looks like each project had a global tool that handled 'mousedown', 'mousedrag', and 'mouseup' events, another set of handlers for `activeLayer` for 'mousedown', 'mousedrag', and 'mouseup' events, and also `selectedItems` has a handler for 'mousedrag'. I can't keep track of what all the different handlers are supposed to do across projects. I'm guessing that these are the root issue with the flickering you saw.

I would likely just use `paper.view.on` for 'mousedown', 'mousedrag', and 'mouseup' events. When I get an event I would check to see if anything on the layer was hit by using the following:

```
paper.project.activeLayer.hitTest(event.point);
```

Being able to set events on the view is new for paper but very useful. There may be a few other tweaks necessary to handle highlighting unselected items. A relatively straightforward way to handle that is to have a group of selected items and a group of unselected items:

```
unSelectedGroup.on('mouseenter', function() {
    unSelectedGroup.selected = true;
});

unSelectedGroup.on('mouseleave', function() {
    unSelectedGroup.selected = false;
});
```

These should be safe across layers when only one layer is visible at a time. I would set up these group handlers when setting up the images, whether all up front or on an as-needed basis. Alternatively, you could also add `paper.view.on('mousemove', ...)` and handle the 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' events yourself using `hitTest` as shown above, but either approach should work.

I think using a layer-based approach to your images will keep things in sync. There are enough problems with the project-based approach and many different mouse event handlers that you'll be on more stable ground regardless.

Comment: I updated my question with my entire PaperFunctions class so you can see things in context. There's a lot of cleanup it needs but hopefully it makes some sense. I hope it's helpful.

Comment: Thanks for all the information. _I would likely just use paper.view.on for 'mousedown', 'mousedrag', and 'mouseup' events._ View doesn't support these: http://paperjs.org/reference/view/#on-type-function But paper.tool seems like the fitting global equivalent.

Comment: paper's documentation doesn't show them but it is supported in 0.9.25 - see this http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/TU1LCoMwFLxKeBsVxAPoMdpdU0TjqwZ1npioiHj3RumisxiYDzMHoRqZcnr07E1HKRlpLr1a3jJBHI2yOG5kQ5SqzwLjbXB5ZfhEHRoqwAicDJwN0v6SQuO8SOM/uzfLu/HcJ3ZJEf7qmat+EgvvKH+9zy8=. It was recently added.

Comment: If you believe this addresses your question I would appreciate you accepting the answer, not just upvoting it. If not, let me know what is missing.

Comment: Here's a follow-up question regarding loading images and the active layer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785370/paper-js-loading-images-and-the-active-layer